# Changing SVN Repository

Tags: svn, distributed

I checked out a project from SVN server A, but I need to commit my changes back to server B - the repositories on both servers have identical structures. How can I do this with Tortoise SVN?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the Relocate option is for this. Haven't used it till now, so I can't vouch.

**Edit**: Reading some more (http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) it seems it's not what you need. It would work if it's the *same* repository with the address changed, but not if it's a different repository.

You could get a fresh copy from repository B, get a patch from the changes that you made and apply it on the fresh copy. Then you can commit.

Comment: The subversion documentation says that you should not use relocate in this situation (see the link posted by rslite). Maybe you are lucky that it worked...

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you need by using [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re12.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do an:

```
svn export
```

on "Server A".  You'll get the codebase but none of the .svn files.  Then go to "Server B" and check the files in as you normally would.  I'm not sure if Tortoise SVN has the ability to do an export, so you might have to use the command line for it.

Answer (score -1):

Look here:
http://wsmoak.net/subversion/demo/tsvn-checkout.html

You can set the correct URL repository when you checkout.